# How to express the idea that those with power are supposed to lead by example?

Tags: example, obligation

I was thinking of "noblesse oblige" (noble blood commands), but that's not quite it. I'm looking for a word or simple phrase that conveys the expectation that those with power, i.e. leaders, are expected to set a good example.

Comment: What's wrong with "Leaders should lead by example"?

Comment: There's always de Maistre - "Every nation gets the government it deserves."

Comment: The concept of servant leadership might be useful here, as people who espouse the practice of servant leadership often lead by example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following phrase may convey the  meaning  you are suggesting:

> With great powers comes great responsibilities.

Comment: Great expression of a great idea :).

Comment: Is it responsibilities or responsibility?

Comment: The original quote is, "With great power comes great responsibility."